# Oracle SQL CREATE TABLE takes too long time or not able to create (without CREATE TABLE works)

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

Any one can give some input here.

I am using this structure to create the table,

```
create table user.sales_fill as
select
        a.name
        ,gender
        ,a.age
        ,b.sales
        , 1 as logic
from
          (select distinct
                              name, age, gender
             from cust_info                 )a
          left join
                    sales b
                    on
                              a.age  = b.age
                              and a.gender = b.gender
 ;
```

when I only use the SELECT part it only takes 7.5seconds to showing the results.

```
 select
            a.name
            ,gender
            ,a.age
            ,b.sales
            , 1 as logic
    from
              (select distinct
                                  name, age, gender
                from cust_info
                                  )a
              left join
                        sales b
                        on
                                  a.age  = b.age
                                  and a.gender = b.gender
     ;
```

but if i Add 'create table' on top of the this select code. I never able to get the table created.

i have right to create the table if i use the the following the table created (but not the right content)

```
create table user.sales_fill as  
select

                gender
                ,age
                ,sales
                , 1 as logic
        from  sales 
         ;
```

Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: Your syntax is not correct.  These queries will return errors because of a missing `FROM` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry for the error. i have the from in the sub query. That is not the reason.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry for the error. i have the from in the sub query in the reality. That is not the reason. could I modify the question also. the point is, if I only run the 'select' part is working.but when i add the 'create table' it does not work any more. i also tried use create table but delete the left join part, (test am i have right to create table) and it also works

Comment: Are you sure that the SELECT is returning all the rows when it returns in 7.5 sec?  It may only take 7.5 sec to return the initial dataset and take just as long as the CREATE TABLE when returning all rows.

Comment: @saritonin Yes. really sure. that is why is so strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-create the table by adding `where rownum = 0` to the end of the query. Then do separate inserts:

```
CREATE TABLE misery
AS
SELECT a.col1
     , a.col2
     , a.col3
     , b.col4
  FROM loves  a
       INNER JOIN company b ON (a.col1 = b.col1)
 WHERE a.ROWNUM < 1;


INSERT INTO misery( col1
                  , col2
                  , col3
                  , col4 )
    SELECT a.col1
         , a.col2
         , a.col3
         , b.col4
      FROM loves  a
           INNER JOIN company b ON (a.col1 = b.col1);

INSERT INTO misery( col1, col2, col3 )
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
      FROM andhow
     WHERE NOT EXISTS
               (SELECT NULL
                  FROM andhow
                 WHERE     andhow.col1 = misery.col1
                       AND andhow.col2 = misery.col2
                       AND andhow.col3 = misery.col3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite the subquery so that it doesn't need to explode the imploded rows (JOIN ON DISTINCT):

```
select
    *
from 
    cust_info 
join
    sales
on
    cust_info.age  = sales.age 
    and cust_info.gender = sales.gender
union
select
    name,
    age,
    gender,
    null
from 
    cust_info
where
    not exists(
        select
            *
        from
            sales
        where
            sales.age=cust_info.age and
            sales.gender=cust_info.gender
    )
```

This way it should not be confusing to the optimizer.
Also to note: the `create table as` could be slow because it duplicates indexes from the scanned tables. You can try `create view` (which also has the advantage of not taking space and auto-updating with the updated tables), or you can try an explicit `create table` without indexes and `as...` and only then `insert into ... select ...` .